# How to test web service with list input?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, netbeans-7

Hey I'm using NetBeans and I am using it's [Test](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower-code-ws.html#test-ws) feature.

It works fine when input is string but how can I test it with when input is `java.util.list`?

All I see is an open textbox, I tried doing something like `new List` or comma seperated value, but none worked.

The same with custom objects, how can I test those?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying that for a while. And believe me I tried with a lot of possibilities.

But then I thought about it, and realized that the NetBeans Tester does not make any conversions to the data that you enter. This means, it is not intelligent enough to convert your `String` input to a Java specific object (`java.util.List`).

And if you think about it, it is alright. Because [Web Services Definition Language (WSDL) uses XSD as its type system](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types) and therefore, there is a [limited group of types we can use](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes) (without making it too complicated).

So my recommendation is to keep your Web Service parameters as simple as possible (int, string, another string, another int, and so on).